# Scroll Java script automatico

Tags: javascript, html

Buenos días en mi pagina tengo un sistema de scroll automático el cual recorre una lista de arriba hacia abajo y al llegar al fondo vuelve y así infinitamente, el tema es que necesito es que baje la lista completa luego suba y cuando llegue al tope nuevamente la pagina haga reflesh para actualizar si se han hecho cambios en el contenido de la información. El código que utilizo es el siguiente.

```
<?php 

mysql_close($link);
?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {
            //Get the HTML of div
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //Get the HTML of whole page
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><center></center></head><body>" + 
              divElements + "</body>";

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

javascript:location.reload();          
        }
       //auto scroll

            var $el = $(".table-responsive");
            function anim() 
            {
                var st = $el.scrollTop();
                var sb = $el.prop("scrollHeight")-$el.innerHeight();
                $el.animate({scrollTop: st<sb/2 ? sb : 0}, 120000, anim);
            }
            function stop()
            {
                $el.stop();

            }

                anim();

            $el.hover(stop, anim);

        //fin auto scroll

    </script>
```

Probé con: 
location.reload(); en diferentes puntos pero no logro hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: Php no va a hacer scroll nunca. Tendrás que hacerlo en JavaScript.

Comment: ahí modifique la pregunta, si estoy utilizando JavaScript.